# How does an IDE create executable files?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, ide

How exactly does an integrated development environment create executable files using a compiler?

Comment: It doesn't.  A linker does.  The IDE just asks the linker to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Specially on which programming language are we talking about. It case of a compiled language, IDE abstracts the compilation process into a single click and runs the compiler with the right flags and options.
For example if you use an IDE for writing C programs, when you click to compile your program, the IDE may run a command like this:
`gcc -o ../bin/hello-world -O2 hello-world.c`
Most IDE's give you the option to choose a different compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The linker generates the executable file from the object files, and dependent static and shared libraries. It does that by resolving symbols and replace them by addresses to the source code in the file or externally in libraries.

More formally (from the ANSI C standard aka. C89, section 6.2.2/2) the linker generates a set of translation units and libraries that constitutes the entire program of a particular identifier with external linkage denotes the same object or function. Within one translation unit, each declaration of an identifier with internal linkage denotes the same object or function. Each declaration of an identifier with no linkage denotes a unique entity.